# ValueError: Missing scheme in request url: h in scrapy

Tags: python-2.7

my code is giving me the output for webscraping but showing some value **error:Missing** scheme in request **url: h**

i have tried to change `start_urls = ['http://books.toscrape.com/']` to `self.start_urls = ['http://books.toscrape.com/']`, but the same error is showing up

Comment: Please refer [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please provide some more code so we can understand what is your problem

Comment: Need to see the full code. Where do you want to change this? In another class? Method? In which method?